# I can't execute BasicReport class C#

Tags: c#, selenium, axapta, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am working on the test automation of the ERP dynamics ax 7 with selenium.
So I record scenarios with task recorder on dynamics ax 365, and to generate the report I used extentreports 2.41.0, for that I created the class BasicReport:

```
  using NUnit.Framework;
 using RelevantCodes.ExtentReports;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace GettingStartedWithLoadTesting
 {
[TestFixture]
public class BasicReport
{
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartReport()
    {
        string pth = 
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;

        string reportPath = projectPath + "Reports\\MyOwnReport.html";

        extent = new ExtentReports(reportPath, true);

        extent.AddSystemInfo("Host Name", "MININT-F36S5EH")
            .AddSystemInfo("Environment", "QA")
            .AddSystemInfo("User Name", "Mohamed Amine");

        extent.LoadConfig(projectPath + "extent-config.xml");

    }

    [Test]
    public void DemoReportPass()
    {
        test = extent.StartTest("DemoReportPass");
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
        test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, "Assert Pass as condition is True");
    }

    [Test]
    public void DemoReportFail()
    {
        test = extent.StartTest("DemoReportFail");
        Assert.IsTrue(false);
        test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, "Assert Pass as condition is Fail");

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void GetResult()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stackTrace = "<pre>" + 
    TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "</pre>";
        var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;

        if (status == NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.TestStatus.Failed)

        {
            test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, stackTrace + errorMessage);
        }
        extent.EndTest(test);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void EndReport()
    {
        extent.Flush();
        extent.Close();
    }


 }
 }
```

and when I run the project, this class is ignored.
then in the test class above that I want to run, I instantiated the class, but I can't call the methods contained in the class

```
using System;
using GettingStartedWithLoadTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication;
using MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Enums;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.TestTools.Dispatcher.Client;
using MS.Dynamics.TestTools.DispatcherProxyLibrary.ApplicationForms;
using MS.Dynamics.Performance.Framework.TaskRecorder;
using MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using RelevantCodes.ExtentReports;

namespace TatAutomationFramework.Web

{
[TestClass]
public sealed class TestFullScenarioBase
{
    StringBuilder sb;


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the test context. Use the property for setting test transactions 
  in the performance tests.
    /// </summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        Client.Close();
        Client.Dispose();
        _userContext.Dispose();
    }

    private DispatchedClient Client;
    private UserContext _userContext;
    private TimerProvider timerProvider;
    [TestInitialize​]
    public void TestSetup()
    {



        // For multi-user uncomment following lines
        //if (this.TestContext != null)
        //{
        //   timerProvider = new TimerProvider(this.TestContext);
        //}
        SetupData();
        _userContext = new UserContext(UserManagement.AdminUser);
        // For multi-user testing use this line
        // Client = new DispatchedClientHelper().GetClient();
        Client = DispatchedClient.DefaultInstance;
        Client.ForceEditMode = false;
        Client.Company = WellKnownCompanyID.USMF.ToString();
        Client.Open();
    }

    private ClientContext CreateClientContext()
    {
        if (timerProvider != null)
        {
            return ClientContext.Create(Client, timerProvider.OnBeginTimer, 
 timerProvider.OnEndTimer);
        }

        return ClientContext.Create(Client);
    }

    private PurchTable PurchTableForm;
    private PurchCreateOrder PurchCreateOrderForm;
    private string PurchCreateOrder_PurchTable_OrderAccount;
    private string PurchTable_PurchLine_ItemId;
    private string PurchTable_InventoryDimensionsGrid_InventSiteId;
    private decimal PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchQtyGrid;
    private decimal PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchPriceGrid;
    private PurchEditLines PurchEditLinesForm;
    private string PurchEditLines_PurchParmTable_Num;
    private void SetupData()
    {
        PurchCreateOrder_PurchTable_OrderAccount = "US_TX_008";
        PurchTable_PurchLine_ItemId = "A0002";
        PurchTable_InventoryDimensionsGrid_InventSiteId = "2";
        PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchQtyGrid = 3m;
        PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchPriceGrid = 20m;
        PurchEditLines_PurchParmTable_Num = "3";
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFullScenario()
    {



        using (var c = this.CreateClientContext())
        {
            using (var c1 = c.Navigate<PurchTable>("purchtablelistpage", 
 Microsoft.Dynamics.TestTools.Dispatcher.MenuItemType.Display))
            {
                PurchTableForm = c1.Form<PurchTable>();
                using (var c2 = c1.Action("SystemDefinedNewButton_Click"))
                {


 Microsoft.Dynamics.TestTools.Dispatcher
.Client.Controls
.CommandButtonControl.Attach(PurchTableForm,"SystemDefinedNewButton")
.Click();
                    using (var c3 = c2.Attach<PurchCreateOrder>())
                    {
                        PurchCreateOrderForm = c3.Form<PurchCreateOrder>();

 PurchCreateOrderForm.PurchTable_OrderAccount
 .SetValue(PurchCreateOrder_PurchTable_OrderAccount);
                        PurchCreateOrderForm.OK.Click();
                    }
                }

                PurchTableForm.LineSpec.MarkActiveRow();

  PurchTableForm.PurchLine_ItemId.SetValue(PurchTable_PurchLine_ItemId);

  PurchTableForm
 .InventoryDimensionsGrid_InventSiteId
 .SetValue(PurchTable_InventoryDimensionsGrid_InventSiteId);
                PurchTableForm.PurchLine_PurchQtyGrid
 .SetValue(PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchQtyGrid);
                PurchTableForm.PurchLine_PurchPriceGrid
  .SetValue(PurchTable_PurchLine_PurchPriceGrid);
                Microsoft.Dynamics.TestTools.Dispatcher.Client
  .Controls.CommandButtonControl
 .Attach(PurchTableForm,"SystemDefinedSaveButton").Click();
                PurchTableForm.Purchase.Activate();
                PurchTableForm.ButtonConfirm.Click();
                PurchTableForm.Receive.Activate();
                using (var c4 = c1.Action("buttonUpdatePackingSlip_Click"))
                {
                    PurchTableForm.ButtonUpdatePackingSlip.Click();
                    using (var c5 = c4.Attach<PurchEditLines>())
                    {
                        PurchEditLinesForm = c5.Form<PurchEditLines>();
                        PurchEditLinesForm.GridParmTable.MarkActiveRow();
                        PurchEditLinesForm.PurchParmTable_Num
  .SetValue(PurchEditLines_PurchParmTable_Num);
                        PurchEditLinesForm.OK.Click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BasicReport BsRep = new BasicReport();

}
```

}

Comment: What is an error ?

Comment: I have no error, in fact I'm working on Unit Test Project, and when I run the project, the BasicReport class doesn't run and the DemoReportPass and DemoReportFail () don't generate in the test explorer part, I just find the tests that I've recorded and imported.

Comment: Please Ishita Shah, I have TestClass that containes my tests, and I want to know how can I execute BasicReport with my unitTest Project, because when I execute my unit test project, only the TestClass class is executed, BasicReport is ignored !!

Answer (score 1):

The scenario which you are following is different and can not help you to archive the desired result: Changes which you should need to make,

-You can not invoke TestNG annotation within same class by send time, You have already invoked annotation for TestClass, So TestNG can't invoke it for BasicReport class.

-In order to make it happen, You need to invoke each required Extent Report object into your Test Class. And you need to call Common methods from Base Class by extending it.  Dest class : Baseclass

-If you wants to create single report, for all your Test then only define in Basic Report class. Else, You can invoke Report creation before @Test annotation for each single Test. So your creation has been invoked.

-Manage TestNG annotation with TestClass and call methods from BaseReport, You just need to call it by extending it.

Thus, You have to manually call all Base Class method. You cant invoke it by TestNG within your current execution.

Comment: Ok Thank you. can I have your email adress ?

Comment: We can't share personal details on stackoverflow.  If you stuck somewhere, feel free to share here.

Comment: Ok! I wanna just need some other explications, because I didn't inderstand.

Comment: I inherited from the basicReport class, when I instantiate BasicReport and I call methods

         BasicReport obj = new BasicReport();
            obj.StartReport();
            obj.GetResult();
            obj.EndReport();
I have this error message:  

Test method TatAutomationFramework.Web.TestFullScenarioBase.TestFullScenario threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need to pass parameterized constructor of class name with Driver in BaseReport class, 
As like:
public class pageLoadUtility extends commonUtility
{
 WebDriver driver;

 public pageLoadUtility(WebDriver driver)
 {
  this.driver = driver;
 } 
}